# Asset are not accesible laravel valet

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-valet, valet

I am trying to setup an existing laravel project in my localhost. I am using Linux Mint along with Valet Linux 2.0

Valet linux works fine as I am able to setup new laravel project which works fine. But now I am trying to setup an existing laravel project. Project is running, all links are working. But none of the static files like js, css, images are loading. I am getting 500 status code for all static files. Not able to understand what is going wrong, I have checked .htaccess also.

I will be thankful if anyone can help.

Comment: Not sure, but Valet uses NGINX so .htaccess is irrelevant.

Comment: setting up new laravel project works perfect. Not sure why not able to setup existing project!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with Valet.

Try to move your static files from **root** folder to **public** folder.
This fix worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).